# Регулярное выражание ".[пробел]A-Я"

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как сформулировать регулярное выражение, чтобы можно было бы вырезать строку после первого появления набора символов `.[пробел]A-Я`. Вырезка выполняется методом `replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`.

Входная строка

```
Позволяет узнать, имеется ли строка. Содержит ли текст элемента страницы
клавишу-ускоритель.
```

Выходная

```
Позволяет узнать, имеется ли строка.
```

Помогите пожалуйста. Сам пробовал, но вообще никак не сработало.

Comment: добавь пример входных и выходных данных, а также добавь свои попытки которые не работали

Comment: И в чём сложность отсечь по `/\. [А-Я]/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться следующим регулярным выражением для извлечения строки до первой точки

```
/^(.+\.)(?=\s+[А-ЯЁ])/
```

и таким, для извлечения строки после первой точки

```
/.+\.\s+([А-ЯЁ].*)$/
```

Comment: простите меня, я ошибся написав ДО, а нужно было ПОСЛЕ встречи набора символов. Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы подправить?

Comment: @user200192 поправил ответ, оставил оба варианта.

Comment: спасибо огромное вам

Comment: @user200192, `Ё` потерялось.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, поправил ответ

Answer (score 2):

```
replaceFirst("[ .А-ЯЁа-яё].*", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Я в этом плоховато разбираюсь, но я бы сделал бы так:

```
replaceFirst(". [А-ЯЁ].*", "");
```

Но лучше так, чтобы сохранялась точка

```
replaceFirst(" [А-ЯЁ].*", "");
```

Строка:

```
Как сформулировать регулярное выражение, чтобы можно было бы вырезать строку 
до первого появления набора символов .[пробел]A-Я. Вырезка выполняется 
методом replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement).
```

Выходная строка:

```
Как сформулировать регулярное выражение, чтобы можно было бы вырезать строку 
до первого появления набора символов .[пробел]A-Я.
```

Comment: спасибо, работает:)

Comment: `Ё` потерялось.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен. спасибо